# Stop System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle inertia if collision with another shape happens in WPF touchscreen app

Tags: c#, wpf, touchscreen, matrix-transform

I am working on touchscreen app. This app is for a certain industry, but the general ideals are all that is needed to explain issue. To start, im doing a crash course on WPF and am allowing a user to add a new command (Shape - Rectangle) then will assign functions to it. Example, they can add one, then add second, then a third and so on positioning them where they want.

What i would like to find out is how to tell the API when inertia is occurring and say a user touches a shape then flings it across screen, for the event to not only complete when it reaches the edge of the screen (already does this), but also if it intersects or hits another shape. Below is the general code for a quick basic proof of concept.

```
void Window_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Get the Rectangle and its RenderTransform matrix.
            Rectangle rectToMove = e.OriginalSource as Rectangle;

            Matrix rectsMatrix = ((MatrixTransform)rectToMove.RenderTransform).Matrix;

            // Rotate the Rectangle.
            rectsMatrix.RotateAt(e.DeltaManipulation.Rotation,
                                 e.ManipulationOrigin.X,
                                 e.ManipulationOrigin.Y);

            // Resize the Rectangle.  Keep it square 
            // so use only the X value of Scale.
            rectsMatrix.ScaleAt(e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X,
                                e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X,
                                e.ManipulationOrigin.X,
                                e.ManipulationOrigin.Y);

            // Move the Rectangle.
            rectsMatrix.Translate(e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X,
                                  e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y);

            // Apply the changes to the Rectangle.
            rectToMove.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform(rectsMatrix);

            Rect containingRect =
                new Rect(((FrameworkElement)e.ManipulationContainer).RenderSize);

            Rect shapeBounds =
                rectToMove.RenderTransform.TransformBounds(
                    new Rect(rectToMove.RenderSize));

            // Check if the rectangle is completely in the window.
            // If it is not and intertia is occuring, stop the manipulation.
            if (e.IsInertial && !containingRect.Contains(shapeBounds))
            {
                e.Complete();
            }

            if (e.IsInertial)
            {
                //convert current moving rect to new rect drawing type
                var tempRect = new Rect(Canvas.GetLeft(rectToMove), Canvas.GetTop(rectToMove), rectToMove.Width, rectToMove.Height);
                //we need to convert SytsemWindows.Shapes.Rectablge to SystemWindows.Drawing.Rect first
                //List<System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle> removeCurrent = Commands.Where(r => r != rectToMove).ToList();
                //List<System.Windows.Rect> coordinates = Commands.Where(r => r.Name != rectToMove.Name).Select(r => new Rect(Canvas.GetLeft(r), Canvas.GetTop(r), r.Width, r.Height)).ToList();

                List<System.Windows.Rect> recs = new List<Rect>();

                List<Rectangle> test = Commands.Where(r => r.Name != rectToMove.Name).ToList();

                foreach (System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle re in test)
                {
                    if (re != rectToMove)
                    {
                        recs.Add(new Rect(Canvas.GetLeft(re), Canvas.GetTop(re), re.Width, re.Height));
                    }
                }

                //if rect item is in motion inertia and it intersects with any of pre made command rects, then stop.
                if (recs.Any(c => c.InteriorIntersectsWith(tempRect)))
                {
                    //There is overlapping
                    e.Complete();
                }

            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

The problem is inertia works fine. Once a second shape is then added to the canvas, inertia no longer works. The user can click and drag them but when trying to flick the shapes they stop instantly as if it reports from all positions that it is intersecting with another shape even when they are no where near each other. Any ideas on what i am doing wrong? [image: Example after user has added one or more items, the touch drag and fling breaks]

Comment: The reason for this request is so i can learn about touch screen. Currently been doing windows and Web MVC, Web API, Javascript, C#, etc for decade plus now. Wanting to create a touch screen app in WPF, but i will be allowing the user of it to design the layout and button positions, as well as button programming what each button does for them. So looking at this so when they have some items already set on the screen, those will be locked, they can add new item, fling it to a position and will set correctly. Just a extra FYI on what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Besides that it is unclear whether you ever set the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top properties of a Rectangle, be aware that these aren't affected by a RenderTransform.